# How to compare best speech recognizer for iPhone?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I have find out following speech recognizer libraries for iPhone.

1) mememe:        http://www.memememobile.com/company/overview/

2) OpenEars :      http://www.politepix.com/openears

3) iSpeech:         http://www.ispeech.org/text.to.speech.tts.saas.api

4) creaked:       http://www.creaceed.com/ceedvocalsdk/features.html

I don't know how to choose better framework among this, Please guide me to do the same.

Comment: To choose a framework, create 4 demo apps and use one framework in each one of the apps. Now test all the apps yourself and see which framework recognizes the speech best. Also check how good & comprehensive documentation is available for them. Ease of use and ease of integration is also a factor.

Comment: Hi Aziz, OpenEars & iSpeech are free to used & i did the demo too but unable to compare other framework as they are paid. do you know the quality of paid frameworks?

Comment: Trial version from Creaceed is [free upon request](http://www.creaceed.com/assets/Tarif_CeedVocal_SDK.pdf). Email Mememe and ask for evaluation version of their SDK.

Comment: Which of them is best for indian accent ?

Answer (score 1):

For **mememe** framework, you can checkout their free iphone app

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/me-shops/id421830161?mt=8

The app is free, but the framework is not. :(
Although, the speech recognizer in APP is gr8 and much faster than other frameworks.

**OpenEars** is client-side framework and will only work for those words/sentences mentioned in the dictionary fie that you have to create. So if you have to recognize all the words in english language, you have to add ALL the words in that file. Its more suitable if the speech commands are predefined and less in number.

**iSpeech** is a server-side free framework and you require to obtain an API key to use it. It does not require you to specify any dictionary file and therefore I will recommend this if you are looking for an free framework. If money isnt any constrain, go for mememe.

Comment: Shri, Is iSpeech free library?